# How to add button google search in this form?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there can someone help me, I want every keyword list, there is a google search button, and when I click on it, it will open a new browser tab, can anyone help me, I don't understand coding at all, so I ask for help here, I'm attaching a screenshot, thank you

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>TRENDING</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <style type="text/css"> -->
        <!-- h3 span { -->
            <!-- font-size: 22px; -->
            <!-- margin-left: auto; -->
            
        <!-- } -->
        <!-- h3 input.search-input { -->
            <!-- width: 100px; -->
            <!-- margin-left: auto; -->
            <!-- float: right -->
        <!-- } -->
        <!-- .mt32 { -->
            <!-- margin-top: 32px; -->
        <!-- } -->
    <!-- </style> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function() {$('table').DataTable();} ); </script>
</head>
<body class="mt32">
    <!-- <div class="container"> -->
        <!-- <h3> -->
        <!-- <span>RESULT</span> -->
        <!-- </h3> -->
    <!-- </div> -->
    
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">keyword</th>
<th title="Field #2">products</th>
<th title="Field #3">date</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>smooth operator</td>
<td align="right">583</td>
<td align="right">1642435207616</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>horse</td>
<td align="right">583</td>
<td align="right">1642435207616</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. If you do not understand coding at all, then SO is likely not for you yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example -

note I cannot use the drawCallback but need to use `on("draw"` PLUS a draw()  to make sure the buttons are also added on the next page of the pagination

`drawCallback` is called for EACH row, so this code is not useful

<s>$table = $('table').DataTable({"drawCallback": addButtons})</s>

The opening of the window is blocked here at SO but works in the
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lams4ntj/)

```js
const addButtons = settings => {
  $('#dt1 tr td:nth-child(1)').html(function() {
    return `<button type="button" title="google search" class="py-0 btn btn-dark btn-sm search">${this.innerText}</button>`
  })
  $('#dt1 tr td:nth-child(4)').html(function() {
    return `<button type="button" title="google trends" class="py-0 btn btn-secondary btn-sm trends">${this.innerText}</button>`
  })
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $table = $('table').DataTable();
  $table.on("draw", addButtons)
  $table.rows().invalidate().draw(); // not sure WHY I need to do this to have the FIRST draw trigger

  $table.on("click", ".search", function() {
    window.open(`https://google.com/search?q=${this.innerText}`, '_blank');
  })
  $('tbody').on("click", ".trends", function() {
    window.open(`https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now 7-d&geo=US&q=${this.innerText}`, '_blank');
  })
});
```

```css
.search, .trends {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>BACKUP</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
</script>

</head>
<table id="dt1" class="table table-striped mt32 customers-list">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">Keyword</th>
<th title="Field #2">Products</th>
<th title="Field #3">Date</th>
<th title="Field #4">Google Trends</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>golf just play it</td>
<td align="right">302</td>
<td align="right">1642887886267</td>
<td>golf just play it</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>go little rockstar tiktok</td>
<td align="right">980</td>
<td align="right">1642888240211</td>
<td>go little rockstar tiktok</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>gorila</td>
<td align="right">709</td>
<td align="right">1642888326752</td>
<td>gorila</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>google arts and culture</td>
<td align="right">23</td>
<td align="right">1642888331842</td>
<td>google arts and culture</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>goat case</td>
<td align="right">1099</td>
<td align="right">1642888338561</td>
<td>goat case</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>goth youtuber</td>
<td align="right">334</td>
<td align="right">1642888346327</td>
<td>goth youtuber</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>goots</td>
<td align="right">56</td>
<td align="right">1642888351273</td>
<td>goots</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>godlike</td>
<td align="right">360</td>
<td align="right">1642888743165</td>
<td>godlike</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>very good very nice</td>
<td align="right">3257</td>
<td align="right">1642889189771</td>
<td>very good very nice</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>navy blue and gold</td>
<td align="right">2613</td>
<td align="right">1642889973714</td>
<td>navy blue and gold</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>its a good day to read a book bookworm book dragon</td>
<td align="right">66</td>
<td align="right">1642889988276</td>
<td>its a good day to read a book bookworm book dragon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>peach and goma teddy</td>
<td align="right">918</td>
<td align="right">1642889994665</td>
<td>peach and goma teddy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>i paused the golden girls to be here</td>
<td align="right">91</td>
<td align="right">1642890006415</td>
<td>i paused the golden girls to be here</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, perfect, you are my hero, this is what I was looking for, but there is a small problem here, when I move the page, the button disappears, can you fix it, again I thank you very much guys

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SuY4bXx3 here it is the code, sorry I dont knoh how to post code in comment

Comment: my bad sorry, i meant when next page, like page 2, the buttons are not showing, here it is example https://jsfiddle.net/r52efg81/

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much, I appreciate it sir, hope you have a wonderful day

Comment: ah, very strange, people as good as you, why are they like that, if only I could do something for you, but unfortunately I can't do anything, God will repay your kindness friend

Comment: hey mate, I just update my code, i want the data in the 3rd row to be the same as the 1st row, so the numbers are replaced, is that possible? if that's not possible, could you fix the google trends link line 30, so that the "inertext" contains the first row, sorry to bother you again, That would be the last edits I would be interested in! You're more than welcome to say no :)

Comment: the code https://jsfiddle.net/iconx/mkngcd84/11/

Comment: no problem sir, I'm not in a hurry, whenever you can if you are interested, thank you so much :)

Comment: Hey mate, i have to fixed this, https://jsfiddle.net/iconx/mkngcd84/63/ but when i choose the page 2, the link in Google trend row not direct correctly, like the page 1, can you help me to fix it ? TIA

Comment: thank you sir, so on the first page, the data in the "keyword" column when clicked they go to google search, and the data in the google trends column they go to google trend, everything works fine, but when I move to page 2 or next page, the data in the google trends column, they don't go to the google trends link, but instead to google search, it should be the same as before, hope you understand, sorry for my bad english

Comment: You only use half my code and I told you not to use drawcallback: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lams4ntj/

Comment: Note I gave the second button a class of trends so we do not need to use the nth-child on the click handler

Comment: Perfect, thats work, thank you so much sir I realy appreciate it :)

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>TRENDING</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <style type="text/css"> -->
        <!-- h3 span { -->
            <!-- font-size: 22px; -->
            <!-- margin-left: auto; -->
            
        <!-- } -->
        <!-- h3 input.search-input { -->
            <!-- width: 100px; -->
            <!-- margin-left: auto; -->
            <!-- float: right -->
        <!-- } -->
        <!-- .mt32 { -->
            <!-- margin-top: 32px; -->
        <!-- } -->
    <!-- </style> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function() {$('table').DataTable();} ); </script>
</head>
<body class="mt32">
    <!-- <div class="container"> -->
        <!-- <h3> -->
        <!-- <span>RESULT</span> -->
        <!-- </h3> -->
    <!-- </div> -->
    
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">keyword</th>
<th title="Field #2">products</th>
<th title="Field #3">date</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>smooth operator <a target="_blank" style="font-size:70%" class="py-0 btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="//www.google.com/search?q=smooth operator">Google search</a></td>
<td align="right">583</td>
<td align="right">1642435207616</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>horse <a target="_blank" style="font-size:70%" class="py-0 btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="//www.google.com/search?q=horse" >Google search</a></td>
<td align="right">583</td>
<td align="right">1642435207616</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


</body>
</html>
```